# Anime about a boy and a girl chased by a group of thiefs

Tags: nadia-the-secret-of-blue-water

I remember watching a anime in early 2000 (the series itself may even be older) It was about a young girl and boy who were getting chased by a group of thiefs.

The girl possesed some sort of blue jewel/gem which they were trying to steal. And in the end the boy and girl prevented some kind of world war/domination plan. Also the girl found out some information about lost family during the journey I believe

The girl had black hair, and allot of jewelry. I also believe she had a red vest with a white shirt underneath it. The clothing looked a bit like that of a pirate.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. It could be a number of things, including [Nadia of Blue Water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia:_The_Secret_of_Blue_Water). What color was the gems, what did the main characters looks like. The [suggested guidelines](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892) have not been met.

Comment: @Krazer Nadia of blue water it is. Recognised the girl immediately. Ill add some off the details for this to be a valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*Nadia: The Secret of Blue Water*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia:_The_Secret_of_Blue_Water):

> The series centers around Nadia, a young girl of unknown origins, and Jean, a young French inventor. Early in the story, the two protagonists are chased by Grandis Granva, Sanson, and Hanson, a group of jewel thieves who pursue Nadia for the blue jeweled pendant she possesses. After being rescued by Captain Nemo and his submarine, the Nautilus, the jewel thieves and the young protagonists join forces and participate in the struggle against the Neo-Atlantean forces, who seek to dominate the world.

[image: Gone Fishin']